# how to query in mongodb with loop in same collection, until i find null or empty value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have stacked in a nested object. here is my collection.

```
{
"key": 1,
"subKey": ""
},
{
"key": 2,
"subKey": 1
},
{
"key": 3,
"subKey": 2
},
{
 "key": 4,
 "subKey": 3
}
```

I want to query `Key:4`, which gives me result

```
{
 "key": 4,
 "subKey": 3
}
```

after getting result i want to query `"subKey": 3` as a `key:"$subKey"` and   i want to run a loop, until i find a empty subKey in our case It is `Key:1`. and whenever i found an empty `subKey` i want it document as a parent.

In the end, I want the result

```
{
 "key": 4,
 "parent":{"key":1,"subKey":"",....}
}
```

or similar.

Is it possible by using MongoDB built-in function? if not available how do I achieve this goal?

also, I want an alternative solution for it if there is.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

Comment: @manan5439 could you approve the below answer if it was helpful? Else let us know what is missing?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve using `$graphLookup`

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MFBxPhdiEUM)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$key", 
      connectFromField: "subKey",
      connectToField: "key",
      as: "keys"
    }
  }
])
```

If you want a match filter add it,

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2ZZ-bVt4u3g)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      key: 4
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$key",
      connectFromField: "subKey",
      connectToField: "key",
      as: "keys"
    }
  }
])
```

**Important consideration:**

> The $graphLookup stage must stay within the 100 MiB memory limit. If allowDiskUse: true is specified for the aggregate() operation, the $graphLookup stage ignores the option

To transform the data, you cannot have duplicate keys in `parent` object. So `parent` should be an array

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NCP3cGIMvwC)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      key: 4
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$key",
      connectFromField: "subKey",
      connectToField: "key",
      as: "keys"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "parent": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$keys",
          "as": "res",
          "in": {
            "key": "$$res.key",
            "subKey": "$$res.subKey"
          }
        }
      },
      "key": "$key",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      keys: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: it is helpful , but i want only one object of parent. In your example it returns all parent, but i want last,which is not belongs to any parent. In your example i only want key 1 as a parent object not array.